# How do I specify a fixed number of colors to appear in a color bar that labels binned data in an R plot generated with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted a US map in which different counties are colored according to the value of a quantity called AQI. The code is the following:

```
my_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = AQI, geometry = geometry),
          color = "#ffffff", size = 0.05) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "green", high = "orange", guide = guide_colorbar(nbin=10))
  labs(fill = "AQI")
```

The color bar next to the map displays a continuous gradient of colors from green to orange. What I really want, though, is the bar to display only one shade of green from 0 to 50; one shade of yellow from 51 to 100; and one shade of orange above 100. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The colour scale is continuous as the `AQI` (Air Quality Index?) is most probably numeric/integer (it is impossible to tell without sample data).

You can make it categorical using the `cut()` function in `base` R:

```
# hypothetical AQI
AQI <- 0:200

AQI_cat <- cut(AQI, breaks = c(0, 50, 100, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

```
> table(AQI_cat)
AQI_cat
   [0,50]  (50,100] (100,Inf] 
       51        50       100
```

Now we pass `AQI_cat` to the `fill` argument and then use `scale_fill_manual()` to specify the fill colours we want for each category:

```
my_data$AQI_cat <- AQI_cat

my_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = AQI_cat, geometry = geometry),
          color = "#ffffff", size = 0.05) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "orange")) +
  labs(fill = "AQI")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well (and yes, AQI is the air quality index). One minor detail: the color bar displays the lowest values (0-50, in green) at the top, and the highest values (100-Inf, in orange) at the bottom. Is there a way to reverse that order, so that the low values appear at the bottom and the high values at the top?

Comment: Change one line in the code `scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "orange"), guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.